# Excel: Can I do sumifs with calculations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am doing some recalculations in Excel on a long list to prepare it for statistical analysis in other programs and I am having troubles with one thing I want to do.

I have a list of some variables, among them an identifier, a date variable and a numerical variable. I need to add a variable that sum the numerical variable from all instances that lies within 365 days of the instance with the same identifier. That is relatively easy doable with sumifs(). But I also want to add a weight to the numerical value so instances that have a date value close to todays value have a higher weight than those further back in time (yesterday 364/365 weight, a month ago 335/365, tomorrow a year ago 1/365 etc.

Is there any way to do that with functions?

```
#     A         B           C         D
1    ID#    datenumber    value    newvar
2    Ken    01-01-2015    1000     somevalue
3    Ida    01-01-2014    1000     somevalue
4    Ida    01-06-2015    1234     somevalue
5    Ida    01-10-2015    5678     somevalue
6    Ida    01-12-2015    1000     y


y = weighted sum of all values of all Ida within one year, line 3 and 4 above.

The newvar sumifs y would be (if "ID#" was in cell A1):

=SUMIFA(C:C,A:A,A6,B:B,"<"&B6,B:B,">"&B6-365) or 1234+5678 = 6912

The "weighted sumifs" would be y = (182/365*1234)+(304/365*5678) = 5344.38
```

I guess I could make a new column with the weighted value on a specific date, do the newvar for all instances with that datenumer, copypaste the values in place then move a day up and repeat it with the instances with that datevalue etc through VBA  but that kind of hackery would really limit the usability of the workbook in other areas. So I am hoping someone have a solution with cell functions instead of VBA.

Comment: Question & comment: 1) The weighting sounds like you want it to be transient (always based on dates relative to  "today").  Is that correct?  2) The data structure you describe is generally bad practice because it overly complicates things.  It gets messy to intermingle data and summaries.  It is much cleaner to put the summary information in a separate table.  If that's a problem, putting it in a separate column is better than intermingling records.

Comment: 1) Not relative to "today" today but relative to the datenumber in the instance. So the newvar doesn´t change unless I add instances with datenumber within one year before the instance and there WILL be added new instances back in time. 2) yes it will be a a bit complex but it is nessesary since adding more data back in time WILL improve the quality of the newvar GREATLY when used in the statistical analysis. When doing the analysis in R or SPSS it will be a snapshot of the data with the quality it had when exported to a CSV file but with the possibility of improving on subsequent snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

Damn, that was way easier than I imagined. Sumproduct alows you to do array-like manipulations on the individual values before you add them up

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=A6)*(B2:B6<B6)*(B2:B6>B6-365)*C2:C6*((B2:B6)-(B6-365))/365)
```

The (A2:A6=A6)*(B2:B6<B6)*(B2:B6>B6-365) are the conditions

The C2:C6 are the values that are to be considered (if they meet the conditions above)

The ((B2:B6)-(B6-365))/365 are the weight that are to be added to the values that have met the conditions