# Get last occurrence in a list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list in `sheet1` and want to get last occurrence of each product right in front of it in `bank` page.

Here is the formula I'm working with:

```
=INDEX(sheet1!$Y$52:$Y$1000,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000)*($C218=sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000))-1))
```

It returns a result which doesn't match the latest result I expect.

I tried this formula in another test page which only has 30 items to search among and it works ok in that file. but in my main subject file, it gives me wrong result.

I'm going to attach my file so you can look through it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0mdhh2PWmIwUEU1MUVMX1l2TVE/view?usp=sharing

and here is the screenshot for the ones who need to look at the problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Questions need to be self contained. Please [edit] your question to include some example data. We are not going to download a file from the internet as it is not safe to do so

Comment: Why do you have `-1` in your formula? If you use only `MAX(ROW(sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000)*($C218=sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000))`, does it give you the row you expect?

Comment: @DavidPostill well i didn't find anyway for uploading an excel file to my question

Comment: @MátéJuhász i'll give a try to your formula. however, i got the formula on one of my internet searchs. this link: http://trumpexcel.com/2014/04/find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-list-in-excel/

Comment: @Unknown You could take some screenshots. Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you. See [Excel: Changing and updating a future value based on past occurrence and lookup in a table](https://superuser.com/q/1007013) for an example.

Comment: @Unknown Or just [edit] and add some sample data. See [Excel: Can I do sumifs with calculations?](https://superuser.com/q/1006730) for an example of that. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) for help on formatting such data. You can also use [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to generate a nice text table to add to your question.

Comment: @MátéJuhász i tried your formula too. but i got the same wrong result. for example: for a product with code of 2168, in bank page, it says i have 36 of it with this formula. but in sheet1 page which shows the real count, i have zero of it. i'm going to upload some screenshots here.

Comment: What values are incorrect and what should they be?  One possible problem is that you are returning a worksheet ROW number from your SUMPRODUCT formula, but indexing into an array that starts at ROW 52, and you are not compensating for that difference.

Comment: @Unknown Sample data in the question is better. Then people can test with your data.

Comment: @MátéJuhász He is using the `-1` because he did not understand the explanation of that portion of the formula he copied.  In that example formula, the array starts at row 2

Comment: ok i uploaded both sample data and screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formula you copied, you apparently did not understand the significance of the `-1`.  The array started at row 2; since the SUMPRODUCT portion returned an absolute row number, the `-1` compensated for that.

In your case, your array starts at row 52, so you need to subtract 51 in order to compensate.

For example:

```
=INDEX(sheet1!$Y$52:$Y$1000,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000)*($C98=sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000))-51))
```

A shorter formula, to accomplish the same purpose:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($C108=sheet1!$I$52:$I$1000),sheet1!$Y$52:$Y$1000)
```

This works because if `LOOKUP` does not find a number that is equal or greater than the lookup, it will match the last number in the array.  The `1/...` portion returns an array of `1`'s and `DIV/0` errors.  So the last `1` matches the last instance where `C108` matches; and we return from the corresponding position in the `Y` column.

Here are screenshots showing the desired results (according to your screenshots):

[image]

[image]

Comment: i did as you mentioned. but nothing changed. problem not solved yet.

Comment: @Unknown It works on the workbook you downloaded.

Comment: i have a question: why would this formula work out in a small quantity but it wouldn't work on my file ? i made a sample file like the link i copied the formula from and it worked

Comment: do u have any other suggestion for fixing my main problem ? i mean giving the last occurance

Comment: @Unknown I assumed from your workbook, and the screenshots you posted, that `0` is the correct return value for 2168.  If that is not the case, then clarify.  Either of the formulas I supplied work on your downloaded workbook.  How much larger is your real data?

Comment: that's exactly what i mean ! the file you're working on, is my main file which has about 300 products and have 1000 in and out occurance totally. let me give a try to your formula.

Comment: i'm really happy with your answer ! i used your short formula and it worked. tnx a lot